# I am trying to convert the blank values of my csv file to the mean of the columns but it is giving "could not convert string to float: '-' " error

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-3.6

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer 
data = pd.read_csv("austin_weather.csv")
data = data.drop(['Events', 'Date'], axis = 1) 
X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = data.iloc[:, 18].values
data = data.replace('T', 0.0)
imputer = Imputer(missing_values="-", strategy="mean", axis = 0)
imputer.fit(X[:])
```

the imputer function is not able to convert the "-" blank value to the mean of the respective column

Answer (score 0):

For the depreciated class [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer) parameter `missing_values` is either string `NaN` or a number.

So you can first replace all `-` values with `np.nan`: `X.replace('-', np.nan)` and then call imputer.